# how to avoid null check

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin

I have a repository class like this:

```
interface TodosRepository : CrudRepository<Todo, Long> {
    fun findByUid(uid: String): Todo?
}
```

and a method that can mark this todo as done:

```
fun markAsDone(uid: String): ResponseEntity<String> {
        var todo = todosRepository.findByUid(uid)
        if(todo == null){
            return ResponseEntity("Not found", HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
        }
        todo.status = 1
        todosRepository.save(todo)
        return ResponseEntity.ok("Saved")
    }
```

IntelliJ ask me to replace the `todo == null` with an elvis operator:

```
fun markAsDone(uid: String): ResponseEntity<String> {
        var todo: Todo? = todosRepository.findByUid(uid) ?: return ResponseEntity("Not found", HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
        todo.status = 1
        todosRepository.save(todo)
```

but then, it asks me to use the null check when setting the status to 1 with `todo?.status = 1` 
the thing is that I think it shouldn't ask me, because at that point, I'm pretty sure that `todo` is not null anymore.
Is there any workaround or I maybe misunderstood something on Kotlin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you could make the variable non-nullable to fix this. Probably also a `val`.

```
val todo: Todo = todosRepository.findByUid(uid) ?: return ResponseEntity("Not found", HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
```

**Edit:** omitting the return type should also work to infer the non-nullable `Todo` type.

The automatic change that IntelliJ suggested would've worked smoothly if you didn't have an explicit type; it seems like it chose to keep it unmodified instead of changing it to non-nullable, which somewhat defeats the purpose of the hint.

```
val todo = todosRepository.findByUid(uid) ?: return ResponseEntity("Not found", HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
```

Comment: but `findByUid` returns null if it is not found

Comment: If it returns null, then the method will immediately return by the elvis operator.

Comment: That shouldn't  be a problem if you're using `?:` after it. In fact, you can try omitting the explicit type altogether, I think you'll get `Todo` inferred.

Comment: well, for some reason, the message asking me to add a null check on `todo.status = 1` is missing now, and I didn't changed anything, it is like the last snippet now, without any warning...and yes, omit the return type also works